# CentOS 6.5 Connections drop randomly

Tags: networking, centos

I have a CentOS 6.5 installed on my ESX as a virtual server. When I working with my server via SSH (or any other connection on any other port), sometimes I lost any type of connection to my server for at least 10 minutes and I have to wait that long or reboot my server using ESX.

When I try to find the problem using traceroute, I realised that the server itself drops the connections.

I have nothing installed on my server to limit connections or any othe control over ports or connections.

I have no rule in my iptables related to this problem.
What can cause this problem and how can I fix it?

**Edit:**
The output of iptables -L -n -v:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
5150K 7108M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
  216 12201 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   31  1865 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
15156  857K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
   51  2580 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53 
 140K 9807K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 
10516 8594K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
  110  6588 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10000 
   80  3924 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080 
 9838  644K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
4137K  694M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: how can I check it?

Comment: You may believe there are no iptables rules at issue, but it would be helpful to be able to confirm that.  Could you post the output of `iptables -L -n -v` into your question?

Comment: I dont undrestand this down votes!!

Comment: My downvote was because your question is vague and I had to ask you for (relevant) log information. My close vote is because you don't know how to check your logs so you don't have sufficient skills for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I asked this question because I dont have sufficient skills to solve my problem!

Comment: And also I asked question about logs because I dont know what I have to search inside my logs! There is a lot of log but I dont know the exact problem source so I have nothing to search for! Give me a start point.

Comment: S.Yavari, please don't take this personally, but **just because you don't know the answer to a question, that doesn't make it a suitable question for SF**.  You may wish to read [our guide on what's on-topic here](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), but that underlying issue is this: you are expected to have a good basic grounding in the field about which you are asking questions before you ask them here.  PS Try looking in `/var/log` while `ssh`ing in to see which logs are updated by `ssh`-related ativity.  Those will be the logs of interest at disconnection time.

Comment: @MadHatter I underestand what you say, thank you so much for your comment. Actualy I have this problem for almost one month and I had so many search around it. I have sufficient skills to manage my servers but I don't have sufficient skills to solve this problem. Please help me to find a way to solve this. Also my question about logs is, what do you need to know from logs? I have so many logs here.

Comment: And about SSH logs, disconnection is not just from SSH. I lost all of my connections to my server. This is some kind of networking problem. So when I lost my SSH connection I can not find updated log file because my connection to server is lost and after reconnecting all of logs are changed.

Comment: My other searches lead me to an IP conflict problem in network. Is there any way to find such a conflict?

Comment: Talk to the network admin at the colo.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bigger issue with your infrastructure... Likely a physical server or networking problem.

I hate to give you such basic troubleshooting steps, but it sounds necessary:

- Are there other virtual machines on this server?
- Do those virtual machines have accessibility issues at the same time your CentOS VM does?
- Do you have VMware Tools installed in the CentOS virtual machine?
- What type of hardware is being used here? Is this consumer or workstation hardware? *(You should never really need to reboot your ESXi host to solve an in-VM problem)*
- What are you connecting to the server from? *Is this a workstation problem?*
- What is between the you and the server? *Switches, networks, firewalls, etc.*

Comment: 1. I have 3 other VM on this machine.

Comment: 2. Other virtual machines have this problem too but not at the same time.

Comment: 3. No I have no VMware tools installed

Comment: 4. I just reboot my virtual machine not my ESXi.

Comment: 5. I connect to server from my laptop over Internet.

Comment: This sounds like your server is in a hosting or co-location environment. Is there some who actually manages the hardware? Can you ask them?